# Merge users between multiple installations?

Tags: 7, users

I'm faced with a particularly tricky task.

I currently have a public facing website with a user base.  I have a few custom fields attached to the users for things like first and last names.

Now, I have an intranet site as well.  I wish to sync the users from the public facing website (PFW) to the intranet site.  I have to copy more than just the custom fields, I also have to make sure that the unique IDs for each user are the same in the intranet site as they are in the PFW.  How can/should this be done?

EDIT: I should mention that the users that already exist in my intranet database are just test users - they can be destroyed.